# How to center div element (right: 50% Doesnt work)

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

I'm trying to center a `div` element, but when I use this:

```
position: relative;
float: right;
right: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

I get the following:

[image]

It just centers the right edge of the element and everything else goes to left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to read "[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

For Horizontal:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

For Horizontal and vertical:

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%; 
tranform:translate(-50%, -50%);
```